# How to calculate a percentage and use result in progressbar?

Tags: counters, calculations

With the progressbar package, I want to show bars on pages depending on a counter.

Progressbar works like:

```
\progressbar{0.7}
```

I use the calc package anyway, so I thought it should be easy to calculate the ratio for the bar for each page, like this:

```
\newcounter{y}
\setcounter{y}{5 / 1}  % check that calc is working

\newcounter{total}
\setcounter{total}{30}
```

But, none of the below seem to work:

```
\progressbar{\value{y}/\value{total}}\\
\progressbar{\value{y} / \value{total}}\\
\progressbar{\they{}/\thetotal{}}\\
```

I get the error: *Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package [progessbar](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/progressbar) uses packages `calc`'s `\real` which accepts only a decimal number, not a ratio. Package `calc` provides `\ratio` but unfortunately it seems `\real{\ratio{\lenA}{\lenB}}` is not legal syntax.

Hence, in despair, you may use:

```
\makeatletter
\expandafter\progressbar\expandafter {\strip@pt \dimexpr \value{y}pt/\value{total}\relax}
\makeatother
```

This should be wrapped in a macro, naturally.

Comment: Special thanks for this answer - I finally switched to this solution since it turned out that pgfmath conflicted with some other package on Linux and Windows (on OS X it had worked). Its obviously better to avoid using additional packages. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Counters (and the math that used to manipulate them) use only integers, so you could never end up with `\progressbar{.7}`.

`progressbar.sty` uses TikZ, so you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{progressbar}

\def\total{30}
\newlength{\basicwidth}
\setlength{\basicwidth}{5in}

\newcommand{\pbar}[1]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\barpc}{#1/\total}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\pbar{15}%
\progressbar{\barpc}\\
\pbar{20}%
\progressbar{\barpc}\\
\pbar{10}%
\progressbar{\barpc}\\
\pbar{5}%
\progressbar{\barpc}\\

\end{document}
```

[image: progressbar.sty exx]

Comment: Loading the beast TikZ only for a simple operation is not convenient. Replacing that call with `\usepackage{pgfmath}` makes the code still working, just more efficiently as you don't make use of TikZ elsewhere. BTW: I think the OP is looking for some solutions to package [`progressbar`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/progressbar) where the argument is not a counter ;)

Comment: Absolutely. I *think* I knew that. Making the change… Thanks.

Comment: I read up on `progress bar.sty` (thanks for the pointer) and altered my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  The pgfmathsetmacro was the missing link!  So here is my MWE, now bysed on your help. (Cannot past it here, will put it in answer.)

Comment: @sgmoye: Well done!

Answer (score 1):

My solution based on the first answer looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{progressbar}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newcommand{\tutprogress}{%
    \stepcounter{tutpageCounter}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ratio}{\value{tutpageCounter}/\totvalue{tutpageCounter}}
    \progressbar{\ratio}

}

\begin{document}

\progressbarchange {ticksheight=1,borderwidth=0.8pt,tickswidth=1.0pt,filledcolor=gray!50,emptycolor=gray!10}
\progressbarchange {subdivisions=\totvalue{tutpageCounter}}
\newtotcounter{tutpageCounter}


\tutprogress{}
\tutprogress{}
\tutprogress{}
\tutprogress{}
\tutprogress{}
\tutprogress{}
\tutprogress{}
\tutprogress{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For rating purpose, my answer based on [@sgmoye](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231501/225624)'s and [@Philippp](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231510/225624)'s answer  would look like,

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{progressbar}

\def\totalvalp{5}
\newcommand{\pbar}[1]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ratio}{#1/\totalvalp}
    \progressbar{\ratio}

}

\progressbarchange {ticksheight=1,borderwidth=0.8pt,tickswidth=1.0pt,filledcolor=gray!50,emptycolor=gray!10}
\progressbarchange {subdivisions=5}

\begin{document}

\noindent\pbar{1} % for rating 1/5
\noindent\pbar{2} % for rating 2/5
\noindent\pbar{3} % for rating 3/5 
\noindent\pbar{4} % for rating 4/5 
\noindent\pbar{5} % for rating 5/5

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]